# How to recover a merge commit after a rebase on the same commit?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, commit, rebase

Suppose this:

```
mkdir test; cd test
echo "1" > file1; git init; git add .; git commit -m "initial - file 1"   # 1st commit on master
echo "2" > file2; git add .; git commit -m "file 2"                       # 2nd commit on master
git checkout -b newbranch                                                 # creates newbranch
echo "1" >> file1; git add .; git commit -m "changed 1"                   # 1st commit on newbranch
git checkout master                                                       # goes to master
echo "2" >> file2; git add .; git commit -m "changed 2"                   # 3rd commit on master
git merge newbranch -m "merge commit"                                     # merge newbranch on master
echo "3" > file3; git add .; git commit --amend -m "merge commit"         # amend merge commit and adds file3
git rebase HEAD~2                                                         # don't change anything, just leave
ls                                                                        # there isn't file3 anymore!
```

Is there a way to recover the merge commit so the changes that were amended on it aren't lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes you made are still in your *reflog*.

After the accidental rebase (I'm assuming it's accidental, since you're talking about "lost" commits), run `git reflog`.

Find the entry just below the last "rebase:" line in the topmost set. The commit hash to the left of it is the amended merge commit before you started rebasing.

Comment: Thx but any of the commits on `git reflog` shows `file3`. Did `git whatchanged` on all commits.

Comment: @bitlogic Check again. Running your above script, followed by `checkout HEAD@{4}`, restores `file3`.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. It's there. Strange is the fact that `git whatchanged` doesn't show the file being added!